# MSBuild timed out

Tags: c#, xml, msbuild, tfsbuild

I keep getting this error:

```
error MSB4018: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
```

It would appear that everything is building correctly, but once a certain time limit is reached (about 14 minutes), I get this timed out message.  I've been searching all over for ways to increase the length before timing out, but can't find anything that works.  Is there an option to put in the TFSBuild.proj file for this?

Answer (score 2):

The error number indicates that the build terminated unexpectedly.

You appear to be calling a web/network resource in your build process - this times out on occasion, causing the sporadic error.

Look at your build process to find out where you are calling this external resource and figure out how to either avoid it or resolve the timeouts.